# Android SwipeViews + TitleStrip + ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments

My new project consists of a Navigation Drawer with 6 fragments ( **Audi** / **BMW** / **KIA**... car brads ). I want each Fragment to have 2 other fragments  ( **Models**, which will have a `ListView` with car models and the second fragment, called **Pictures**, it's obvious what that contains). I don't like tabs, that's why I chose `TitleStrip` with swipe navigation between the fragments.

BMW.java

```
public class BMW extends Fragment {

    CollectionPagerAdapter mCollectionPagerAdapter;

    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(com.zenyt.R.layout.fragment_bmw, container, false);

        mCollectionPagerAdapter = new CollectionPagerAdapter(
                getFragmentManager());

        // Set up action bar.
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();

        // Specify that the Home button should show an "Up" caret, indicating
        // that touching the
        // button will take the user one step up in the application's hierarchy.
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        // Set up the ViewPager, attaching the adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.bmw_pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mCollectionPagerAdapter);
        return rootView;
    }

    public class CollectionPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        final int NUM_ITEMS = 2; // number of tabs

        public CollectionPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int i) {
            Fragment fragment = new TabFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(TabFragment.ARG_OBJECT, i);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_ITEMS;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

            String tabLabel = null;
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    tabLabel = getString(R.string.label1);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    tabLabel = getString(R.string.label2);
                    break;
            }

            return tabLabel;
        }
    }
    public static class TabFragment extends Fragment {

        public static final String ARG_OBJECT = "object";
        private ListView myListView;
        private String[] strListView;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            Bundle args = getArguments();
            int position = args.getInt(ARG_OBJECT);

            int tabLayout = 0;
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    tabLayout = R.layout.models;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    tabLayout = R.layout.pictures;
                    break;
            }

            View rootView = inflater.inflate(tabLayout, container, false);

            return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

In `TabFragment`, I want fragments instead of layouts (`models` and `pictures`). How can I do that?

models.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tab1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    >

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView2" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Models.java

```
public class Models extends Fragment {

    private ListView myListView;
    private String[] strListView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(com.zenyt.R.layout.models, container, false);

        myListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(com.zenyt.R.id.listView2);
        strListView = getResources().getStringArray(com.zenyt.R.array.bmw_list_data);
        ArrayAdapter<String> objAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, strListView);
        myListView.setAdapter(objAdapter);

        myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {



            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that I solved it by myself. All I had to do was to change a bit the PagerAdapter, like this:

```
 public class CollectionPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        public CollectionPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch (arg0) {
                case 0:
                    return new Bmw1();
                case 1:
                    return new Bmw2();
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

            String tabLabel = null;
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    tabLabel = getString(R.string.label1);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    tabLabel = getString(R.string.label2);
                    break;
            }
            return tabLabel;
        }
    }
```